# Websocket from Arduino to Android: send integer instead of text

Tags: android, websocket, arduino, esp8266

I'm trying to send an integer from a Wemos D1(ESP8266) as server using the Link2004/Arduino WebSockets library, to an Android client using OkHttpClient library, using `sendBIN(num, buf, buf_len)` as follows:

```
int n=1234;
uint8_t * buf = (uint8_t *) &n;
size_t buf_len = sizeof(n);
webSocket.sendBIN(0,buf,buf_len); // num is set to 0, ( client # 0 )
```

but what I get at the Android end, instead of 1234 I get `d2040000`.

The Android listener looks like this:

```
public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, ByteString bytes) {
    output("Received bytes : " + bytes.hex());
}
```

and the result on the TextView output as I said is `d2040000` instead of 1234 as sent.

Can anyone clarify the confusion?

Comment: You should not convert to hexadecimal representation.

Answer (score 1):

The bytes `0xd2`, `0x04`, `0x00` and `0x00` are the bytes of the 32-bit integer 1234 in [little-endian format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

SO the `d2040000` is a hex-string of those bytes.